# Model event not fired

Tags: events, laravel, model, laravel-4

I'm having trouble firering model events.

currently I have the following

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class ProjectTwitterStatus extends Eloquent {

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $table = 'project_twitter_statuses';

    protected $guarded = array('id');

    public function twitterStatus() {
        return $this->belongsTo('TwitterStatus');
    }

    public function twitterStatusHashtag() {
        return $this->hasMany('TwitterStatusHashtag','twitter_status_id','twitter_status_id');
    }

    public function project() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Project');
    }

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($model)
        {
            echo 'deleting status';
        });
    }
}
```

And the delete is initiated in a helper class:

```
public static function deleteStatus($input_ids, $project) {

    // Make sure ids are in an array
    $twitterStatusIds = (!is_array($input_ids) ? array($input_ids) : $input_ids);

    foreach($twitterStatusIds as $twitterStatusId) 
    {
        ProjectTwitterStatus::where('twitter_status_id', '=', $twitterStatusId)
            ->where('project_id','=',$project->id)
            ->delete();
    }
    // Forget the cache variable
    Cache::forget('twitter-dashboard-statistics-'.$project->id);

    return true;
}
```

the delete works fine, but somehow the model events aren't triggerd. The echo of 'deleting status' is a place holder to display the event being triggerd, I tried several placeholders, dd($model) or creating a file none worked. So I assume the event is not triggerd. Any toughts on the matter?

Comment: Just a hunch, try removing the `SoftDeletingTrait` and try it out.  I'm wondering if it's soft deleting, the delete events aren't being called.  Could be a bug.

Comment: I removed the `SoftDeletingTrait` but that had no effect :(

Answer (score 0):

I know that's not a perfect answer, however I fixed a similar problem by using this:

```
Event::listen('eloquent.creating: ProjectTwitterStatus', function($model)
```

Comment: I just tried this, using `eloquent.deleting` but it did not work :(.

Comment: Is the model deleted from database?

Comment: Yes it is softdeleted from the database. only the event is not fired.

Comment: Can you try `return false` in the event closure? Is it still deleted?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem once again while I was using intervention\image package. I added it to aliases array with the name `ImageEditor` instead of `Image`. Then I created a class `Image` which uses ImageEditor. In an minor update of intervention\image package, my events stopped firing. I tried writing full path of class, use `static::` instead of `Image::` but none of them worked.

Now I changed the alias back to `Image` and renamed my `Image` class to something else, the events started firing again.

Answer (score 0):

I had/have similar problem. I used:

```
model0hasmanyrelation()->delete()
```

and while the records got (soft) deleted, model's event didn't fire. The solution was to use:

```
model0hasmanyrelation->each(function($model0){$model0->delete()});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change this:

```
foreach($twitterStatusIds as $twitterStatusId) 
  {
      ProjectTwitterStatus::where('twitter_status_id', '=', $twitterStatusId)
          ->where('project_id','=',$project->id)
          ->delete();
  }
```

to this:

```
foreach($twitterStatusIds as $twitterStatusId) 
  {
      ProjectTwitterStatus::where('twitter_status_id', '=', $twitterStatusId)
          ->where('project_id','=',$project->id)
          ->first()
          ->delete();
  }
```

This way a model object is actually loading and events are having chance to fire. When calling `delete()` without `first()` Eloquent just executing direct SQL query via Builder.